# Is it possible to merge these two .htaccess lines?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect a link of the form

```
q/search_text/page_number
```

to

```
index.php?page=search&q=search_text&page_num=page_number
```

so I add this line to my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^q/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=search&q=$1&page_num=$2 [L,QSA]
```

which works fine.

But, the problem is that sometimes the user does define the `page_num` for example, `q/search_text`, so I just have to assume that the page number equals one by adding the line to my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^q/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=search&q=$1&page_num=1 [L,QSA]
```

Is there a way to somehow merge these two lines in one `.htaccess` code/line?

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^q/([^/]+)/?([0-9]+)?/?$ index.php?page=search&q=$1&page_num=$2 [L,QSA]
```

php

```
if($_GET['page_num']==='')$_GET['page_num']=1;
```

Comment: Is there a to have `page_num` equal `1` not `''` when the page number is not defined using `.htaccess`?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.